# You are not using binary logging

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am setting up a new server, so I did a fresh install of phpMyAdmin on an Ubuntu-21 with mariadb-server and php-8 installed before,

I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You are not using binary logging in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? It sounds like you just need to update your phpMyAdmin installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an acceptable answer, but I solved this by :

- formatting HD
- reinstalling all from scratch